# A tricky arithmetic progression question

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

> In a question I have to prove that if
>    $\log_l x, \log_m x, \log_n x$ are in AP where $x \neq 1$ and $x > 0$, prove that
>   $$n^2=(l \cdot n)^{\log_l m}$$

My tries:

1. I first converted every term to natural logarithm so I got
   ln (x)/ln (l), ln (x)/ln (m), ln (x)/ln (n)
2. then I multiplied each term by (-1/ln (x)) because there is no x in result so I got
   ln (l),ln (m), ln (n) which are in AP
3. then I used three AP formulas 
   A.M.=(a+b)/2 where a.m., a, b are arithmetic mean, a is first term, b is second term
   T base n =a+(n-1) d where T base n is nth term, d is common difference
   2b=a+c, where a, b, c are 1st ,2nd and 3rd term respectively.
   But on using all these three formulas I am getting only one relation
   m^2=nl
   Please help how I should move forward to solve question

Comment: Are you sure this is correctly worded? As $\ln 1 = 0$, defining $\log_1 x$ doesn't really work because you'd be dividing by zero.

Comment: @Ashkay I read the same thing to start with, but I'm pretty sure now that it's the letter ell, "l", not "1".

Comment: It is el not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\log_a x, \log_b x, \log_c x$ are in AP, then we have 
$$
\log_a x + \log_c x = 2 \log_b x 
$$

Now, we express everything in base $c$ using the change of base formula:
$$
\dfrac{\log_c x}{\log_c a} + \log_c x = \dfrac{2 \log_c x}{\log_c b} 
$$
After this, we divide both sides by $\log_c x$, then multiply both sides by $\log_c b$.
$$
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\log_c a} + 1 &= \dfrac{2}{\log_c b}  \\
\dfrac{\log_c b}{\log_c a} + \log_c b &= 2 
\end{align*}
$$
Now, because $\dfrac{\log_c b}{\log_c a} = \log _a b $ by the change of base formula, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\log_a b + \log_c b &= 2 
\end{align*}$$

Taking $c$ to the power of both sides, we have the following:
$$\begin{align*}
c^{\log_a b + \log_c b} &= c^2 \\
c^{\log_a b}c^{\log_c b} &= c^2 \\
c^{\log_a b} \cdot b &= c^2 \\
\end{align*}
$$

I think the new edit to the problem has parentheses wrong.

Comment: Thank you for ur try but I didnt got it.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? This should be a complete solution.

Comment: I added a couple more steps to make the solution easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

So $\frac{\ln x}{\ln l}, \frac{\ln x}{\ln m}, \frac{\ln x}{\ln n}$ are in AP, which means
$$
\frac{2\ln x}{\ln m} = \frac{\ln x}{\ln l} + \frac{\ln x}{\ln n}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac{2}{\ln m}
  = \frac{1}{\ln l} + \frac{1}{\ln n}
  = \frac{\ln n + \ln l}{\ln l \ln n}
$$
so
$$
2 \ln n = \frac{\ln m}{\ln l} \left( \ln n + \ln l \right).
$$
Can you finish it?

Comment: Ya I can finish and thank you for it but I was also using this identity for so long but I had problem manupilating equation, how did you thought about it at first place.

Comment: @KartikWatwani need to match $n^2$ on the left side...